# Inquiry about topic to ask in superuser forum

Tags: discussion

I have a question about the Microsoft part number that comes with some Microsoft software products boxes like Office and Windows 10.

I would like to ask what part is the number defined as? What is it useful for and what information can we derive from the part number of a Microsoft product? I want to ask from the user point of view.

Can these questions be asked in the super user forum?

an example of the part number i'm talking about which is usually printed in the box that came with the software media (DVD, USB etc) from microsoft is something like this : [QQ2-00036] or this [QQ2-00570]

Comment: 1/ [su] is not a forum 2/ that question would probably be closed as only Microsoft will have such a list.

Comment: Definitely not on topic here at Superuser.  We cannot explain the part number system that Microsoft uses because they don't document that information.  Our speculation of what might be true would be just noise

Answer (score 3):

[I'd point you at my answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298143/135565)

I'd also point you at this part of [our help centre](https://superuser.com/help/asking)

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Finding out what an arbitrary number is dosen't really improve your experience using your computer anyway, and unless MS support asks for it (or you're keeping inventory of these product as a store), the average end user dosen't care.

Comment: Ok, understood. Thank you average end user.,